# How do I link a filtered range from excel to word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

We are using word to print labels with lists of components; say, sku ABC includes components a, b, c, and d, but sku XYZ includes components a, b, and f. Anyway, we have a master excel file that tracks all of these SKUs and their respective components. The excel file is updated frequently, usually just a few skus at a time. Problem is, we have to update the corresponding word label files each and every time.

I know I can link to a range in excel from word, that's simple enough, but we run into the issue of having to re-link to a different range every time a line is inserted to the master file.

Is there a way to link these in a way that would track inserted or deleted lines? Better yet, is there a way to filter what I'm linking to from Word so that the labels reliably reflect the excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort and filter directly from Word by clicking on "Edit Recipient List".

[image]

[image]

To help prevent issues with inserted and deleted rows, it is best to change your data in Excel into an Excel table which automatically creates a dynamic range.

It is also possible to manually create dynamic ranges which will accommodate new/deleted rows but it isn't very simple.